# Windows Authentication with .net 6 (Negotiate) not working - how can I debug?

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, windows-authentication

I have created a very small sample project with .net 6 and enabled kerberos/ntlm authentication by setting the following line in the startup:

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
```

This is just working fine. I get the desired user in a controller by calling this:

```
HttpContext.User.Identity?.Name
```

But then I wanted to integrate this behavior in our existing application (based on the aspnetzero framework) and here it does not work any more. HttpContext.User.Identity?.Name is just null - the user was not set. Of course our application registers a lot of other services and probably one of those additional services breaks the negotiate mechanism.

Has anyone an idea how I can debug this issue? What does "AddNegotiate()" actually change?

Meanwhile after doing more research I remarked, that in the simple working example I have an **"Authorization" header** in HttpContext with a value like "NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGA..." and in the complex example which is not working I don't have this header - but I do have a **"MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN" header** with a value like "a1b57bcf-4708-440d-8f38-c541e1ae77b5".

Is there a component missing which converts the MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN to an authorization string?

**EDIT:**

I found out that the MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN has actually nothing to do with the authentication. And I also found out that I can annotate my controller methods with the following:

```
Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

This will somehow enforce negotiation on this api - unfortunately until now it is only working in IIS Express but not yet in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

When you're hosting in IIS, IIS handles Windows Authentication for you, but you have to tell it to do so by using the web.config file. For example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

There's more information under the IIS heading in the documentation for [Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#iis)